# Grid with Eval expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I use a Telerik RadGrid control and various 'Eval' expressions to show data in my aspx pages:

```
<div>
     Number: <%# Eval("AccountNumber")%>
</div>
<div>
     File: <%# Eval("AccountFile")%>
</div>
...
```

Sometimes my DataSet is empty (ie. the AccountFile may be missing). How do I write the aspx code so as not to show the Div at all if the expression for the Eval is null or empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%# if(Container.DataItem != null){%>
<div>
     Number: <%# Eval("AccountNumber")%>
</div>
<div>
     File: <%# Eval("AccountFile")%>
</div>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the above doesn't work for me. Any other ideas? I tried the following as well, but it didn't work:
<%# (Eval("LeaseTerm") == null) ? "" : ("<div class='instanceRow'>Lease: " + Eval("LeaseTerm") + "</div>")  %>